# Assigning of the variables 'on the fly' from bash terminal

Tags: bash, variables, terminal

Right now I have the following simple variables in my bash script

```
# Please set you name and surname as well as your login on CICADA cluster

prenom="gleb"
nom="novikov"

# Are you Lady or Sir ?
hah="Sir"
```

which then will be used during the execution producing different fun comments in terminal window

```
echo "It's nice to meet you ${hah} ${nom} ${prenom}!"
```

Now I need to add to my script smth which will ask me just as it executed, what is my name ?
what is my surname?
are you lady or sir?

and save all three answers in the variables ${hah} ${nom} ${prenom} which will be used only during this terminal session!

Thanks for any elegant and simpler solutions!

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the `read` shell builtin to read input text and store them into variables. See `help read` for more info.

```
read -p "Enter your 1st name: " prenom
read -p "Enter your surname: " nom
read -p "Are you Lady or Sir? : " hah
echo "It's nice to meet you ${hah} ${nom} ${prenom}!"
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.bash 
Enter your 1st name: gleb
Enter your surname: novikov
Are you Lady or Sir? : Sir
It's nice to meet you Sir novikov gleb!
$
```